# Inertial frame of reference in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

How could we measure [rest mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass) of photon (that would be zero) when we agreed that photon can not be a inertial frame of reference (because of the dominator of Lorentz's transformation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be in a reference frame where the photon is at rest.

Let's suppose you are an inertial observer and you observe a photon. You  measure its energy $E$ and momentum $\mathbf{p}$, finding that $p = E/c$ (if you find something else, either you made some mistakes or your experimental apparatus is not precise enough, or you deserve a Noble prize). And then you use the energy momentum-relation of special relativity theory

$E^2 - (pc)^2 = (m_0 c^2)^2$.

Since you measured $p = E/c$, you can conclude that $m_0 = 0$. This is also the only way for a system to move at the speed of light, otherwise you should need an infinite work to accelerate the system.

Answer (score 2):

You already got a correct answer with a very direct method
showing that photons have zero rest-mass.
There are other more indirect and more accurate methods
to determine the rest mass of photons, or rather to show
it is zero.
For the energy-momentum relation of special relativity
$$\frac{E^2}{c^2}-p^2=(m_0c)^2 \tag{1}$$
there is a corresponding wave equation.
If the photon would have a rest mass $m_0>0$, then the
electromagnetic potentials ($\Phi,\mathbf{A}$) would
satisfy the so-called [Proca equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proca_action#Equation)
$$\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial t^2}+\nabla^2\Phi
  &=\left(\frac{m_0c}{\hbar}\right)^2\Phi \\
-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{A}}{\partial t^2}+\nabla^2\mathbf{A}
  &=\left(\frac{m_0c}{\hbar}\right)^2\mathbf{A}
\end{align}\tag{2}$$
when you choose the Lorenz gauge
$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}=0$.

A derivation of this equation (2) is beyond the scope of this answer.
But at least you can motivate it from (1) by the usual correspondencies
$E \to i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$
and $\mathbf{p} \to -i\hbar\nabla$.

---

This equation (2) has static solutions
$$\begin{align}
\Phi(\mathbf{\mathbf{r}}) &\propto \frac{1}{r}e^{-m_0cr/\hbar} \\
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}) &= \mathbf{0}
\end{align}$$
so that $\Phi$ quickly approaches zero for larger distances
($r\gg\frac{\hbar}{m_0c}$), if $m_0 > 0$.
For rest mass $m_0=0$ this reduces to the well-known [Coulomb potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law#Coulomb_potential)
$$\Phi(\mathbf{r}) \propto \frac{1}{r}$$
So the experimentally observed Coulomb-law is an indication
for photons with rest-mass $m_0=0$.

---

Equation (2) also has wave-like solutions
$$\begin{align}
\Phi(\mathbf{r},t)&\propto\sin(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}-\omega t) \\
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t) &\propto \sin(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}-\omega t)
\end{align}$$
with the dispersion law
$$\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}-k^2=\left(\frac{m_0c}{\hbar}\right)^2$$
For rest mass $m_0=0$ this reduces to the dispersion law
$$\frac{\omega}{c}=k.$$
From this you can derive the wave speed
(both the [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) $v_\text{phase}=\frac{\omega}{k}$
and the [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity)  $v_\text{group}=\frac{d\omega}{dk}$)
to be independent of frequency.

So the experimental fact that the speed of light in vacuum
is the same for all frequencies, is an indication for photons
with rest mass $m_0=0$.

Comment: Why does the potential, u,  satisfy the same equation as the corresponding wave function?

Comment: @jellyears you are right. I confused wave-function with potential (and Klein-Gordon equation with Proca equation). See my corrected answer.